# Compiler problem when using Modelica CombiTable1Ds

Tags: dll, compiler-errors, modelica, dymola

I'm working on the Dymola environment (2019 FD01) and I'm trying to create a model that can read values from a .mat file, more specifically, a weather data matrix of [8761,14].
To do so I'm using CombiTable1Ds with the following configuration

```
Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds combiTable1Ds(
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="Beijing",
    fileName="C:/Users/Folders/Beijing.txt",
    columns=2:14,
    smoothness=Modelica.Blocks.Types.Smoothness.ContinuousDerivative)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-34,-10},{-14,10}})))
```

When I try to run the simulation, I receive the following error

```
Compilation of Unnamed failed.

Compiler message:

Compiling and linking the model (Visual C++). 

dsmodel.c
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: unable to open input file 'ModelicaIO.lib'

Error generating Dymosim.
```

I'm kind of new in this and I don't completely understand this type of error. I've check the .mat file and seems fine (not corrupted, compatible version); I read the documentation of the model and seems well implemented; I've also tried using a .txt file with the format described on the documentation (#1\float Beijing(8761,14)\ and so), but I get the same error.

Anyone has a clue of what may be the problem and how to solve it? I'll really appreciate it
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

That model is supposed to work, and I tested in Dymola 2019 FD01 with DLL-mode activated. The tableName and fileName don't matter for this type of problem.

Things to consider:

- You are using Modelica Standard Library from the Dymola-distribution, right? If you downloading a different version that can cause problem.
- Just to be sure try changing to a new empty folder, to ensure that there are no strange files causing problems.
- Normally this is a problem you should contact your support channel for.